# Converting object type

Tags: c#

I have a base class:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have classes that derive from the base class:

```
public class AddAccountResponse : BaseResponse
{
        public string AcctNum { get; set; }
}

public class AddCustomerResponse : BaseResponse
{
        public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

When an error occurs I have a method that returns BaseResponse.

What is the best way of converting/casting the response from the base to the expected result type? For example:

```
public AddCustomerResponse PleaseAddMyCustomer(CustomerRequest customerReq)
{
    AddCustomerResponse response;

    if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        ...
        BaseResponse base = GetErrorResponse(restResponse);
        return (response.GetType(response))base; <-----
    }
}
```

I know that I can:

```
response = new AddAccountResponse() 
    { 
        StatusCode = base.StatusCode
        ...
    }
return response;
```

Please excuse my simplictic/rather stupid example but I am trying to create a basic example.

Comment: If you expect a static type just cast to `typeof(ThatType)`. If you want a dynamic type that's another issue.

Comment: If you're asking how to convert a base class to a derived class, you can use the [`is` and `as` keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx).

Comment: well, I will have multiple methods and I was trying to figure out how the code between the if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{} could stay the same and base if off of the type of the response. In one method the response will be AddCustomerResponse and the other will be AddAccountResponse.

Comment: A thought occurs to me: does `GetErrorResponse` literally return an instance of `BaseResponse`, or does it return the correct type for the request? You cannot use a cast to actually convert one type to another. If you're trying to change a `BaseResponse` into an `AddCustomerResponse`, you'll have to actually construct a new `AddCustomerResponse` and copy the base fields into it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, GetErrorResponse returns the base. I have been copying the fields but thought there might be another way since they were "related".

Comment: Ah, I see. No, there's no built-in automatic way to do that. It's certainly not something that you can do with a cast (unless you write a custom cast operator for it, but you still have to write custom code). You may wish to look at Automapper, though.

Comment: This problem is a good candidate for the Visitor pattern.

Comment: Can you show us a skeleton of `GetErrorResponse()`? The statement `BaseResponse base = GetErrorResponse(restResponse);` makes little sense to me as you give the method a response and it returns a response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics for that. I created a little program to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string restResponse = "OK";

        // Creates an AddAccountResponse
        var response = GetResponse<AddAccountResponse>(restResponse);
        response.AccountNumber = 0;
    }

    // I converted your `GetResponse` to a generic method `GetResponse<T>`. 
    // The method expects that `T` is (derived from) a `BaseResponse` 
    // and that `T` has a parameterless constructor. 
    private static T GetResponse<T>(string restResponse) where T : BaseResponse, new()
    {
        var response = new T();
        response.StatusCode = restResponse;
        return response;        
    }
}

public class BaseResponse
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public class AddAccountResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

It is a little simplified for demonstration purposes but I guess you get the idea.

Comment: thanks, I will look at it over the weekend. This is what I think I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here. Without generics, you need to define common interfaces for similar behavior.

Is this what you want?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IBaseEntity> entities=new List<IBaseEntity>();
        IBaseEntity acct=new Account() { AcctNum="1001-Q" };
        entities.Add(acct);
        IBaseEntity cust=new Customer() { FullName="Draco Malfoy" };
        entities.Add(cust);

        List<BaseResponse> responces=new List<BaseResponse>();
        responces.Add(cust.GetResponce());
        responces.Add(acct.GetResponce());

        foreach (var item in responces.OfType<AddCustomerResponse>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
        }
        foreach (var item in responces.OfType<AddAccountResponse>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.AcctNum);
        }
    }
}
```

with the following definitions:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}

public class AddAccountResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public string AcctNum { get; set; }
}

public class AddCustomerResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseEntity
{
    BaseResponse GetResponce();
}

public class Customer : IBaseEntity
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public AddCustomerResponse GetResponce()
    {
        return new AddCustomerResponse()
        {
            FullName=this.FullName
        };
    }
}

public class Account : IBaseEntity
{
    public string AcctNum { get; set; }
    public AddAccountResponse GetResponce()
    {
        return new AddAccountResponse()
        {
            AcctNum=this.AcctNum
        };
    }
}
```